# I have a coolant leak, a big one, but my car isnt overheating... whats wrong?

Tags: chevrolet, coolant-leak, impala

Okay, so i have a 2010 impala. Recently i had a very slow drip of coolant from my vehicle. It slowly started to worsen. I got a bottle of kseal and put that into my vehicle, it stopped the leak outta no where. That last 2-3 days. Now my vehicle is literally dripping coolant like a faucet that was left on. Im going through a bottle of coolant in a day. I had a mechanic friend look at it. They changed the water pump gasket because we thought that was the issue. As soon as it was turned on and revved a bit, it started leaking heavily again. So the gasket wasnt the issue. Theres zero coolant anywhere near the radiator. The hoses have no holes. But its leaking somewhere around my belt because its leaking onto my belt and causing the coolant to spread everywhere up under my hood and onto my fans. We looked at the water pump and theres nothing wrong there. Once the car is running and its dripping heavily, i took the radiator hose cap off and it stopped leaking, i put the cap back on and it started leaking heavily again... no one can figure out where its leaking from and my car has been taken apart and put back together several times for this specific reason and my car isnt overheating at all no matter how much coolant i lose. anyone have suggestions?

Comment: fill the coolant system and use air pressure to look for the leak with the engine off,be sure to have good lighting and get help from a friend to look for the leak.

Comment: All I can say is get a BETTER mechanic.  Coolant leaks are not that hard to find since you will see the evidence squirting out.  There are multiple possibilities but a good mechanic will diagnose the problem and fix it rather than just replacing stuff.

Comment: I'd personally have a look at the water pump itself. Most have a weep hole designed to drip coolant when the internal bearing goes bad. Everything you've said seems to indicate the pump to me. Near the belt, a leak that never overheats, drip that progressed to "faucet," etc. Honestly, there isn't much else in that area to leak from. Anyways, best of luck.

Comment: Some cars measure the engine temperature by measuring the coolant liquid temperature. If you remove all the coolant, it will get erroneous temperature readings that looks like the engine is cool, while at the same time the engine is overheating by the lack of the coolant liquid.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was my intake manifold gasket.